# Hiding Developer App from General Public

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Working on my first FB app and making good progress.  I know that non-testers cannot publish items to their timeline from my app, and certainly that non-testers cannot see the activities of testers, but how can I configure it so that non-testers can't view my app at all while it is in development.  Currently, if you type in the correct URL, you can browse the latest progress.  Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to your http://developers.facebook.com
2. Click "Apps" on the top tool bar
3. Click "Edit Settings"
4. Click "Advanced Settings"
5. Click "Enabled" on Sandbox Mode.

Hope this helps